# tar: million of files

Tags: tar, packages

I have to pack circa 7,000,000 small files. I'm looking for an efficient way to do this.

Is tar the best way? What about benchmark tests or any other suggestion?

Comment: In one directory?

Comment: Efficient in what way? Compresionspeed? Filesize? etc.

Answer (score 5):

Some people like [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip). For example that's how Wikipedia packages up complete images.

Comment: I'd go with 7zip.

Comment: Indeed. I'd use 7zip for EVERYTHING, except system backup on Linux. Since the files lose their attributes. That stays in .tar.gz , "but for everything else.." :~)

Answer (score 3):

TAR is actually doesn't have it's own compression. TAR is just merging directories/files into one big file. The speed of creation of tar archive depends more on filesystem and I/O subsystem than on tar itself.
The best way to get the highest compression ratio is to use 7zip (7zr command on *nix/Linux).
The bigger dictionary size you choose - the smaller archive you receive.

For Linux you can try:

```
7zr a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=128m -ms=on /path/to/put/archive.7z folder_to_compress
```

Answer (score 0):

jar is also very nice, as it's a zip (compression) of the files.  If not for the manifest inclusion, it would be close to perfect (as jar seems to exist just about everywhere now)

Comment: fyi, a jar file is a zip file w/ an automatically added manifest. No difference.

Comment: and that's different from my answer how?

Comment: why would you use `jar` over `zip`?